# Display datas in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using Spring MVC 3 and Thymeleaf. I want to display string in the table but there are no results (blank table cell). What am I doing wrong? My controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="table", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public class TableController {
@Autowired
DaneEndpoint daneEndpoint;
public String tabela(Model model){
model.addAttribute("tytul", daneEndpoint.getAll().get(0));
model.addAttribute(model);
 return "table";
    } 
 }
```

and html page (table.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"> 
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h3 align="center">table</h3> 
    <div align="left">
    <form action="table.html"  th:object="${tytul}" method="get">
      <fieldset> 
        <div align="center">
        <table border="1">
          <thead>
             <tr>
               <th th:text="">tytul</th>
             </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             <tr>
                <td th:text=""><span th:text="#{table.tytul}"/></td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table> 
        </div>
      </fieldset>    
    </form> 
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `<span th:text="#{table.tytul}"/>`

`
fetches value from message properties so if table.html is opened directly in browser,it will be blank

If this page is accessed through application, since ,

> `<th th:text="">`

is not valid thymeleaf expression syntax(because of empty string) , parse error will occur.. And

> `<td th:text=""><span th:text="#{table.tytul}"/></td>`

contains span as child of td so, th:text need not be included in td as th:text in td will replace  ultimately..

further meta tag is not closed..

Try this

```
> <!DOCTYPE html>  <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">  <head>
>     <title></title>
>     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
> </head> <body>
>     <h3 align="center">table</h3> 
>     <div align="left">
>     <form action="table.html"  th:object="${tytul}" method="get">
>       <fieldset> 
>         <div align="center">
>         <table border="1">
>           <thead>
>              <tr>
>                <th >tytul</th>
>              </tr>
>           </thead>
>           <tbody>
>              <tr>
>                 <td><span th:text="#{table.tytul}"/></td>
>              </tr>
>           </tbody>
>         </table> 
>         </div>
>       </fieldset>    
>     </form> 
>     </div>  </body> </html>
```

And if value on table need to be displayed when directly opened in browser for prototyping purpose, try this

```
> <!DOCTYPE html>  <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">  <head>
>     <title></title>
>     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> </head> <body>
>     <h3 align="center">table</h3> 
>     <div align="left">
>         <form action="table.html"  th:object="${tytul}" method="get">
>             <fieldset> 
>                 <div align="center">
>                     <table border="1">
>                         <thead>
>                             <tr>
>                                 <th >tytul</th>
>                             </tr>
>                         </thead>
>                         <tbody>
>                             <tr>
>                                 <td><span th:text="#{table.tytul}"/> <span th:remove="all">content</span></td>
> 
>                             </tr>
>                         </tbody>
>                     </table> 
>                 </div>
>             </fieldset>    
>         </form> 
>     </div>  </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you were missing an ending `</tr>` and ending `</div>`. try adding that.